# Different behavior when I running a program compiled with G ++ in Docker

Tags: c++, docker, g++, compiler-optimization

The behavior of the executable is different if it is run inside the docker, or on the host. But this only happens when we change the optimization level of G++.

Compiler:
g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
int main()
 {
    int nOrd =3395;
    char cOrd[] = "003395";
    char cAux2[256];    
    strcpy(cAux2, cOrd);
    int nRest = nOrd % 26;
    printf("BEFORE SPRINTF %s\n\n\n", cAux2);
    sprintf(cAux2, "%s%c", cAux2, (nRest+65));
    printf("AFTER SPRINTF %s\n\n\n", cAux2);
    return 0;
 }
```

If I compile with:

```
g++ -o FastCompile FastCompile.c -DNDEBUG -Os
```

And I run in the host. The output is as expected:

```
BEFORE SPRINTF 003395


AFTER SPRINTF 003395P
```

If I create an image with this executable and run inside the docker, I have:

Docker version 18.09.4, build d14af54266

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
   libssl-dev
COPY fast/ /usr/local/
ENTRYPOINT ["usr/local/FastCompile"]
```

$docker build -t fastcompile .

$docker run fastcompile

```
BEFORE SPRINTF 003395


AFTER SPRINTF P
```

If I remove the -Os and re-compile with:

```
g++ -o FastCompile FastCompile.c -DNDEBUG
```

The behavior is correct inside the Docker.

So,
Is it a Docker problem? Or is it expected behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior.

```
sprintf(cAux2, "%s%c", cAux2, (nRest+65));
```

reads from and writes to the same object.  To fix it you can use `cOrd` in the call so you are not reading from your buffer.  That would look like

```
sprintf(cAux2, "%s%c", cOrd, (nRest+65));
```

---

Also note that `(nRest+65)` gives you a `int`, not a `char` as you format specifier states it should be.  That is also undefined behavior.  You need to cast it to a char to fix it like

```
sprintf(cAux2, "%s%c", cOrd, char(nRest+65));
```

Comment: Isn't there a second undefined behavior since the format string says `%c` but `(nRest+65)` is an `int`?

Comment: This code snippet comes from an old code written in Visual C ++ 6. I will reimplement it to remove the undefined behaviors. Thank